# WordPress на локальной машине не разворачивается - выполняет постоянную переадресацию

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Настраиваю локальный сервер. Поставил стек **LEMP**. Настроил nginx:

```
server {
   server_name asp;

   root /var/www/asp;
   index index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

   location / {
           # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
   }
```

}

В файле **hosts** прописал:

```
127.0.0.1 asp
```

База данных пуста. Если в `wp-config.php` специально указать неверные данные для подключения к бд, то **WP** выводит ошибку подключения к бд и нет никакой переадресации. А как указываешь всё верно, сразу выскакивает переадресация. В чём проблема?

> Страница недоступна Сайт asp выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.
>   Удалите файлы cookie..
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Проблема в неправильных настройках nginx. https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Comment: @KAGGDesign Делаю всё по инструкции, а `nginx` ругается. У меня изначально нет директории `conf` или `global`, а есть `conf.d`. Мне создать директорию `global` в корне каталога `/etc/nginx/`? Если так, то вот ошибка: `nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/global/wordpress.conf:4`